# Expansion Panel List Radio Minimizar Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

sou iniciante no Flutter e gostaria de saber como eu "minimizo" toda minha lista do Expansion Panel quando meu campo de pesquisa tiver focado. O ideal seria minha lista toda minimizar quando focasse este campo de filtro ou ele fosse alterado no onChanged.

Pois enquanto eu filtro com um item da lista maximizado da este erro: '_children[j] is MaterialGap': is not true.

Acredito que se eu minimizar antes de pesquisar, resolva meu problema.

```
      Widget _buildPanel() {
return ExpansionPanelList.radio(
  children: _foundUsers?.map<ExpansionPanelRadio>((_foundUsers) {
        return ExpansionPanelRadio(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          value: _foundUsers.name +
              _foundUsers.remote +
              _foundUsers.usrten.toString() +
              context.hashCode.toString(),
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.person, size: 22),
              iconColor: Color(0xff63a29b),
              title: Text(
                _foundUsers.databases[0].usrten.toString() +
                    ' - ' +
                    _foundUsers.name +
                    ' - ' +
                    _foundUsers.remote,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff63a29b),
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              ListView.separated(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: _foundUsers.databases?.length,
                  separatorBuilder: (_, __) => const Divider(),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(_foundUsers.databases[index].name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Color.fromARGB(150, 0, 0, 0),
                              fontSize: 12)),
                    );
                  }),
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 10),
                width: double.maxFinite,
                height: 30,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Color.fromARGB(255, 99, 162, 155)),
                  ),
                  child: const Text(
                    'Derrubar Usuário',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    UserDatabase value;
                    DatabasesDown value2;

                    value.name = _foundUsers.name;

                    for (DatabasesDown usr2 in value.databases) {
                      value2.id = usr2.id;
                      value2.name = usr2.name;
                      value2.usrten = usr2.usrten;

                      value.databases.add(value2);
                    }

                    listDownUsers.add(value);

                    globals.downAll = false;

                    dialog(context, listDownUsers);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      })?.toList() ??
      [],
);
```

Abaixo o código do campo de filtro:

```
     void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword, List<UserFromDbId> userFromDbId) { List<UserFromDbId> results = []; if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {   results = userFromDbId; } else {   results = userFromDbId
      .where((user) =>
          user.name.toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()) ||
          user.usrten.toString().contains(enteredKeyword) ||
          user.remote.toString().contains(enteredKeyword))
      .toList(); } setState(() {   _foundUsers = results; }); }

[
```

Ao focar este campo de pesquisa, queria que a lista toda "minimizasse"][Lista com o filtro]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

De acordo com umas pesquisas que fiz, utilizando o *Widget* `ExpansionPanelRadio` você não vai conseguir fazer o que deseja... Para isso você teria que utilizar o `ExpansionPanelList` junto com o `ExpansionPanel`.

Com isso em mente, eu montei um exemplo de como é implementado, já com a funcionalidade estilo *Radio* que você precisa.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: GestaoEstoquePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final List<String> logs;
  bool isExpanded = false;

  User({required this.id, required this.name, required this.logs, isExpanded});
}

class GestaoEstoquePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<GestaoEstoquePage> createState() => _GestaoEstoqueState();
}

class _GestaoEstoqueState extends State<GestaoEstoquePage> {
  User? _selectedUser;
  List<User> users = [
    User(id: 1, name: "Teste 1", logs: ["Log 1", "Log 2", "Log 3", "Log 4"]),
    User(id: 2, name: "Teste 2", logs: ["Log 1", "Log 2", "Log 3", "Log 4"]),
    User(id: 3, name: "Teste 3", logs: ["Log 1", "Log 2", "Log 3", "Log 4"]),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SizedBox(
            height: 100,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              child: const Text("Fechar"),
              onPressed: () {
                for (final item in users) {
                  setState(() {
                    item.isExpanded = false;
                  });
                }
                _selectedUser = null;
              },
            )),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ExpansionPanelList(
            expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
              setState(() {
                if (_selectedUser != null) _selectedUser!.isExpanded = false;
                users[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
                _selectedUser = users[index];
              });
            },
            children: users.map<ExpansionPanel>(
              (user) {
                return ExpansionPanel(
                  canTapOnHeader: true,
                  isExpanded: user.isExpanded,
                  headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text(user.name),
                    );
                  },
                  body: ListTile(
                    title: Text(user.logs.join(" -> ")),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

*Pode testar direto pelo [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id).*

Comment: Bom dia @Matheus! Muito obrigado meu querido, alterei para ExpansionPanelList, e inclui o expansionCallback. Dei um setState() no OnTap() e onChanged() do meu campo filtro para fechar toda a lista, conforme vc fez. Funcionou perfeitamente! Responderei abaixo como ficou.

Comment: @VitorBorher não é preciso postar a resolução do seu código. Apenas marque a resposta como aceita, caso tenha resolvido seu problema.

Answer (score -1):

Bom dia Matheus, muito obrigado meu querido. Funcionou perfeitamente!

Obs: não da mais o erro, pois a lista está minimizada, e fica dinâmico igual o Radio, já que utiliza expansionCallback.

Descreverei como ficou o código:

1/3) Alterei meu código para ExpansionPanelList e inclui o expansionCallback:

```
 Widget _buildPanel() {
return ExpansionPanelList(
  expansionCallback: (int index, bool isExpanded) {
    setState(() {
      if (_selectedUser != null) _selectedUser.isExpanded = false;
      _foundUsers[index].isExpanded = !isExpanded;
      _selectedUser = _foundUsers[index];
    });
  },
  key: _formInicioKey,
  children: _foundUsers?.map<ExpansionPanel>((_foundUsers) {
        return ExpansionPanel(
          canTapOnHeader: true,
          isExpanded: _foundUsers.isExpanded,
          headerBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool isExpanded) {
            return ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.person, size: 22),
              iconColor: Color(0xff63a29b),
              title: Text(
                _foundUsers.databases[0].usrten.toString() +
                    ' - ' +
                    _foundUsers.name +
                    ' - ' +
                    _foundUsers.remote,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff63a29b),
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              botaoDerruba(_foundUsers),
              _buildBody(_foundUsers),
            ],
          ),
        );
      })?.toList() ??
      [],
);}
```

2/3) Apliquei setState() no OnTap():

```
  (...)
                   onTap: () {
                  for (final item in _foundUsers) {
                    setState(() {
                      item.isExpanded = false;
                    });
                  }
                  _selectedUser = null;
                },
                onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value, userFromDbId), (...)
```

3/3) Apliquei setState() no onChanged() do meu filtro também, caso o usuário expanda um item da lista após o OnTap:

```
 void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword, List<UserFromDbId> userFromDbId) {
for (final item in _foundUsers) {
  setState(() {
    item.isExpanded = false;
  });
} (...)
```